# Compare column1 in File with column1 in File2, output {Column1 File1} that does not exist in file 2

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Below is my file 1 content:

```
123|yid|def|
456|kks|jkl|
789|mno|vsasd|
```

and this is my file 2 content

```
123|abc|def|
456|ghi|jkl|
789|mno|pqr|
134|rst|uvw|
```

The only thing I want to compare in File 1 based on File 2 is column 1. Based on the files above, the output should only output:

```
134|rst|uvw|
```

Line to Line comparisons are not the answer since both column 2 and 3 contains different things but only column 1 contains the exact same thing in both files.

How can I achieve this?

Currently I'm using this in my code:

```
#sort FILEs first before comparing

sort $FILE_1 > $FILE_1_sorted
sort $FILE_2 > $FILE_2_sorted

for oid in $(cat $FILE_1_sorted |awk -F"|" '{print $1}');
do
echo "output oid $oid"

#for every oid in FILE 1, compare it with oid FILE 2 and output the difference

grep -v diff "^${oid}|" $FILE_1 $FILE_2 | grep \< | cut -d \  -f 2 > $FILE_1_tmp
```

Comment: Given file 1 and file 2 you want to only output `134|rst|uvw|`? Then why doesn't line-based comparison work? If you want to merge rows with matching column 1 from file 1 and file 2 you can use ` join -t '|' file1 file2` and then use `cut` to only output relevant columns.

Comment: My input files contain thousands of lines, impossible to know which line to cut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in `Awk` very easily!

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}FNR==NR{unique[$1]; next}!($1 in unique)' file1 file2
```

`Awk` works by processing input lines *one* at a time. And there are special clauses which `Awk` provides, `BEGIN{}` and `END{}` which encloses actions to be run before and after the processing of the file.

So the part `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` is set before the file processing happens, and `FS` and `OFS` are special variables in `Awk` which stand for input and output field separators. Since you have a provided a file that is de-limited by `|` you need to parse it by setting `FS="|"` also to print it back with `|`, so set `OFS="|"`

The main part of the command comes after `BEGIN` clause, the part `FNR==NR` is meant to process the first file argument provided in the command, because `FNR` keeps track of the line numbers for the both the files combined and `NR` for only the current file. So for each `$1` in the first file, the values are hashed into the array called `unique` and then when the *next* file processing happens, the part `!($1 in unique)` will drop those lines in second file whose `$1` value is not int the hashed array.

Comment: +1 Nice! I think you meant "**... so set `OFS="|"` ...**" in above. I tried to fix it but I am not allowed to edit less than 6 characters, weird.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i understand the explanation completely but do i miss anything? i keep getting syntax error while testing the command. I did some research but found out that the syntax is already correct

Comment: @MFAY: HOw are you running the command? what version of `Awk` do you have?

Comment: @Inian awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS="|"}FNR==NR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' file1.txt file2.txt , awk -W version does not return version

Comment: @Inian  it turns out, Solaris has a really old awk, replace this with nawk, command works perfectly

Comment: @MFAY: Happy you found it useful

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one liner that uses `join`, `sort` and `grep`

```
join -t"|" -j 1 -a 2 <(sort -t"|" -k1,1 file1) <(sort -t"|" -k1,1 file2) |\
   grep -E -v '.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|'
```

`join` does two things here. It pairs all lines from both files with matching keys and, with the `-a 2` option, also prints the unmatched lines from file2.

Since `join` requires input files to be sorted, we sort them.

Finally, `grep` removes all lines that contain more than three fields from the output.