# unable to search in file1 and replace in file2 using sed and xargs for all lines

Tags: awk, sed, xargs

I need to search for each string in file1 and then replace that string in file2 with a string

file1

```
node1
node2
```

file2

```
node1
node2
node3
node4
```

```
cat ~/backup/file1.log | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'sed -i "s/$1/done/g" ~/backup/file2.log' -- > ~/backup/file3.log
```

expected output
file3

```
done
done
node3
node4
```

actual output

```
prints nothing in file3
```

Comment: not encouraging xargs+sh+sed solution (and not sure if it would work), but using `-i` option will write any changes back to `~/backup/file2.log` , so file3 will be empty.. check file2 contents

Comment: You are right, I stripped off i and directed to file, then it got saved. can you post this answer and I will mark it.  coz answer below might be good too but I need to understand and then mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a convoluted `sed`/`xargs` loop when you can do this all in `awk`? Worst of all your command does a new file I/O for every new entry in the first file.

```
awk 'FNR == NR { lines[$1]; next } $1 in lines { $0 = "done" }1' f1 f2 > f3
```

The `awk` command works by marking all the lines int the first file to `lines` array and then in looking-up the second file `$1 in lines` will match those lines in second file whose line contents are hashed in the `lines` array. If so modify the current line to `"done"` and print it `{..}1` or by default print the lines for non-matching lines.

The `$1 in line` could be replaced by `$0 in line` as long as you are matching the contents in both files by the "entire" line. For specific column position matching spell out the actual column.

Comment: can you explain your expression please. am new.

Comment: What do you mean @AhmFM: I've explained it below. Which part you don't understand?

Comment: okay: let me do some reading.. i was looking for FNR, }1 and []

Comment: @AhmFM: I've tried to explain in detail, in another answer of mine. See if you can understand it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45452657/5291015